# How to comment many lines of code? - file weight and performance on page load

Tags: performance, file, filesize, page-load-time

I was wondering if I have a JavaScript plugin, for example, of about 50Kb, does if I comment that out but I load the file anyway in the page, will be weight 50Kb to server side and browser side?

I mean 50kb of JavaScript, commented out at all, but loaded anyway, will afflict the page load performance as well as if it is not commented?

Comment: Most web application frameworks use minifiers for JS, which would not simply not include the commented out code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser will render the page faster, but obviously it won't make any difference for the server. The JavaScript, commented out or not, will still have to be downloaded.

Comment: so it will download but not interpreting the js, will be faster anyway?

Comment: Yes the JS engine will just skip the code. It won't anything to evaluate so, on the client-side, it will be faster.